# Different ways to redirect stderr and stdout to a file in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, stdout, stderr

From what I understand, `2>&1` just means 'send stderr to the same place as stdout'. But for some reason, `1>foo 2>foo` and `1>foo 2>&1` don't seem equivalent.

```
# Assuming file 'out' exists but file 'nosuchfile' doesn't

# 'foo' contains stdout and some partial stderr in CentOS 6
$ ls -l out nosuchfile 1>foo 2>foo
$ cat foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 May 14 14:45 out
ctory

# 'foo' contains both stdout and stderr
$ ls -l out nosuchfile 1>foo 2>&1
$ cat foo
ls: cannot access nosuchfile: No such file or directory
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 May 14 14:45 out
```

Can anyone explain why they behave differently?

Comment: It's probably because stderr is not fully buffered (your first case). In the second example, everything goes to stdout, which goes to file foo; stdout is fully buffered when redirected to a file. See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_05.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`>` overwrites files; `>>` appends to files.

When you write `1> file` *and* `2> file` both streams will overwrite `file` in parallel and may therefore overwrite each other – a typical race condition.

`command 1>> file 2>> file` should keep all output of both streams.

Example:

```
$ n=1""000""000
$ (seq "$n" 1>&2 & seq "$n") 1> o 2> o
$ wc -l o
1000000
$ rm o
$ (seq "$n" 1>&2 & seq "$n") 1>> o 2>> o
wc -l o
2000000
```